# ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm attempting to install Nginx on an ec2 instance using the Terraform provisioner `remote-exec` but I keep running into this error.

`ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain`

This is what my code looks like

```
resource "aws_instance" "nginx" {
  ami                    = data.aws_ami.aws-linux.id
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  key_name               = var.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id]

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = self.public_ip
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file(var.private_key_path)
    

  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum install nginx -y",
      "sudo service nginx start"
    ]
  }
}
```

Security group rules are set up to allow ssh from anywhere.
And I'm able to ssh into the box from my local machine.

Not sure if I'm missing really obvious here. I've tried a newer version of Terraform but it's the same issue.

Comment: What values are you passing in for `var.key_name` and `var.private_key_path`?

Comment: I'm passing in the same .pem keypair file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your EC2 instance is using an AMI for an operating system that uses [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (the default images for most Linux distributions do) then you can avoid the need for Terraform to log in over SSH at all by using the `user_data` argument to pass a script to cloud-init:

```
resource "aws_instance" "nginx" {
  ami                    = data.aws_ami.aws-linux.id
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  key_name               = var.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id]

  user_data = <<-EOT
    yum install nginx -y
    service nginx start
  EOT
}
```

For an operating system that includes cloud-init, the system will run cloud-init as part of the system startup and it will access [the metadata and user data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) to retrieve the value of `user_data`. It will then execute the contents of the script, writing any messages from that operation into [the cloud-init logs](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/logging.html).

What I've described above is [the official recommendation for how to run commands to set up your compute instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html#passing-data-into-virtual-machines-and-other-compute-resources). The documentation says that [provisioners are a last resort](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html#provisioners-are-a-last-resort), and one of the reasons given is to avoid the extra complexity of having to correctly configure SSH connectivity and authentication, which is the very complexity that has caused you to ask this question and so I think trying to follow the advice in the documentation is the best way to address it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin.

I'll have a look at the documentation.